# ngMessages not working correctly with nested input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, ng-messages

I have an input field that is nested within another `<div>` element, and I am trying to use ngMessages on that inside input field, but I can't seem to get it to validate correctly.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-model="object.idnumber" ng-hide="condition.userObjectsHidden">
    <label class="form-control-label col-lg-12">ID Number</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <input type="text" name="idnumber" placeholder="111001111"
        ng-model="user.idnumber"
        ng-pattern="idpattern"
        class="form-control input-lg"
        required="required"></input>
        <div ng-messages="idnumber.$error" ng-if="idnumber.$dirty">
            <p ng-message="pattern">You are wrong!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if it matters in terms of functionality where the `<div ng-messages...>` tag is, but I have also tried having it completely outside of this element with the same results. If I understand Angular and ngMessages correctly, I need to assign `ng-messages` to a directive--`$error` in this case--that I get to by dot-walking across `name` assignments. As far as I know, I have done this with `idnumber.$error`, although to be fair, I have also tried a more extensive dot-walk by using `kiosk-form.uin.$error`, where `kiosk-form` is the name of the entire form.

I have tried both `ng-message="pattern"` as well as `ng-message="required"`. Also, just for clarity, `idpattern` is defined in my Javascript file as a regex string. It is defined correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your form as `kioskForm`and then `ng-messages ="kioskForm.idnumber.$error"`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Why do I even need to use `kioskForm` at all, regardless of how it's spelled? `idnumber` is completely unique; there is not another 'idnumber' nested anywhere else. So by my logic, simply using `idnumber.$error` should automatically map to the only existing element with that name.

Comment: Good to know that :-), Angular maintains an error object for every form with the form name, like `kioskForm.$error`

Comment: Oh it's tied to the form! Great, that helps a lot. Thanks again!

Comment: Pleasure is mine :-)